# Multiple Backgrounds CSS3 problems with IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have more problem with these lines in IE8:

```
 background: url('../images/sabao_x_top.gif') repeat-x top left,
        url('../images/sabao_x_foot.gif') repeat-x bottom left;
```

I use:

```
-pie-background: url('../images/sabao_x_top.gif') repeat-x top left, url('../images/sabao_x_foot.gif') repeat-x bottom left;
    behavior: url(../PIE.htc);
```

PIE, nothin'.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Nothin'.

And now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also target IE8 plus IE7 and IE6 by using

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

This means the conditional will work if it is less than or equal to IE8

Comment: Ok perfect. Now I understood where I was wrong.
I read LTE but in fact the condition is with LT. LessThan vs LessThan or Equal.Ok thanks. But the problem persist.

Answer (score 2):

your sending that script to all versions of ie less than ie8; change your conditional comment to <!--[if lt IE 9]> or <!--[if ie 8]>

Comment: I change with LTE.But the problem persist.

Comment: without seeing your code, i can't help anymore. and the only reason i didn't tell you to use less than or equal to is because your question is only in regards to ie8. i answered your question 14 hours before you accepted the other one. you should ask more your questions more concise and clear.

Comment: The code is all here.
What I need is for these simple lines of code.
The real problem is right here!! The multiple background and IE8!

Comment: no the code is not all there. all of your css and the markup would be all of the code. those css declarations don't help. need them all